# Multiline Link Formatting Conundrum

Tags: css, xhtml

On a webpage, I have markup like the following:

```
<h3>Title Goes here</h3>
<a href="...">Link goes here</a>
<h3>Next title</h3>
<a href="...">Next link</a>
```

Some of these links have very long text and span multiple lines.  I would like the following to occur:

1. There is spacing between the first heading's link and the second heading.
2. Links that span multiple lines have all lines but the first indented.

The way that this is accomplished currently is through the following CSS:

```
h2 + a, h3 + a, h4 + a, h5 + a, h6 + a {
    margin: 0px 30px 20px 5px;
    line-height:1.4;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-indent: -10px;
}
```

The problem comes in because our links have the following formatting:

```
a {
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #900;
}
```

Since the links under the headings have `display: inline-block`, the border-bottom does not go under the text of each line, but rather under the whole box that the link generates.  I'm not sure if there is way to get what I want here, since `display:inline-block` seems necessary to get the margins and indenting that I want, but the border-bottom would only work with an inline element.

Is there a way to have my cake and underline it too, without altering the markup (eg wrapping the `<a>` elements with `<p>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `position: relative` and a negative margin to achieve the indenting effect without resorting to text-indent, which required the inline-block.  I added margins to the headers instead of the links in order to create the necessary spacing.  The CSS is as follows:

```
h2 + a, h3 + a, h4 + a, h5 + a, h6 + a {
    line-height:1.4;
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}

a+h2, a+h3, a+h4, a+h5, a+h6 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just need to alter the line-height to be lower than 1.4? If not, please provide a visual.

Comment: Altering the line-height doesn't seem to help.  A visual is here: http://imgur.com/6BO4e.png

Comment: can you reproduce it in webdevout.net/test ?

Comment: another option would be making an image that's 80-100px tall with repeating dotted borders, and applying it to the anchor so every 10 or so vertical pixels it shows.

Comment: it's probably easiest to do the wrapping. since inline-block has different behaviour than inline, it wont render the border-bottom the same way. it's just natural.